# How to update table in cassandra without specify partition key?

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I have an issue when I want to update column family in cassandra, without specify any partition key, I have errors. I try to use ALLOW FILETERING but always.

`update tablename set field1="newValue";`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use ALLOW FILTERING in updates:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlUpdate.html?hl=update

Compare it to the SELECT syntax:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlSelect.html?hl=update

If it's something you want to do regularly, then you probably have a design issue and the tables should be modeled in a way so you don't need to use ALLOW FILTERING.

If it's just a one time thing, you can always select the keys using ALLOW FILTERING (maybe export them, depending on the size of the result) and then do an update on those keys (IN is supported for primary keys).